# RENAME USER in a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a stored procedure to rename users in my MySQL database:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`%` PROCEDURE `renamedbuser`(
  IN _oldname VARCHAR(200),
  IN _newname VARCHAR(200)
)
BEGIN
  IF (SELECT COUNT(User) FROM mysql.user WHERE User = _oldname) > 0 THEN
  BEGIN
    RENAME USER _oldname TO _newname;
  END;
  END IF;
END
```

When I run this procedure I get the following error:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Operation RENAME USER failed for '_oldname'@'%'
```

It seems to me that when the RENAME USER line executes, it uses the *name* of the variable _oldname as the original username, rather than the *value* that the variable contains.

If I execute something like

```
RENAME USER 'test' TO 'testing';
```

If works as I'd expect, renaming the 'test'@'%' user.

Am I calling RENAME USER incorrectly? Does that statement just not work this way when called from a stored procedure? Is there any way to achieve the behavior I'm looking for?

Comment: It seems odd to make a stored procedure for what already exists as a single-line query.

Comment: @tadman as a little bit of context for why I'm doing it this way, this is part of an application that renames users elsewhere who sometimes, but not always, match up to database users, and I want to first check that the user exists in order to avoid throwing an exception when I try to rename a user that doesn't exist. I can work around the issue in other ways, of course, but making the whole operation into a simple stored procedure seemed like an elegant solution.

Comment: "Elegant solution" and "stored procedures" are often incompatible terms. Application code is easy to change, you just change it, while database schema changes require a *lot* more forethought and planning, you don't just change the production database. It's often better to express this as application logic than to bake it into your database schema for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation of [account names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/account-names.html) it says:

> The user name and host name need not be quoted if they are legal as unquoted identifiers.

I guess that takes precedence over your stored procedure variables. It also says:

> Quote user names and host names as identifiers or as strings, using either backticks (`), single quotation marks ('), or double quotation marks (").

You could try it with backticks, like so:

```
RENAME USER `_oldname` TO `_newname`;
```

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately, this produces the same error as before.

Comment: @jmatula Oh well, it was worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `prepare statement`. I tried this in mariadb:

```
delimiter $$

drop procedure if exists renamedbuser$$
 
CREATE DEFINER='admin'@'localhost' PROCEDURE renamedbuser(
  IN _oldname VARCHAR(200), IN _newname VARCHAR(200)
) 
sql security definer 
BEGIN 
  set @sql = concat('RENAME USER ', _oldname,' TO ', _newname); 
   prepare stmt from @sql;   
  IF (SELECT COUNT(User) FROM mysql.user 
    WHERE User = _oldname) > 0 THEN 
    BEGIN 
      execute stmt; 
      deallocate prepare stmt; 
    END; 
  END IF; 
END$$
 
delimiter ;

                              or

delimiter $$
 
drop procedure if exists renamedbuser$$

CREATE DEFINER='admin'@'localhost' 
 PROCEDURE renamedbuser(IN _oldname VARCHAR(200), 
  IN _newname VARCHAR(200)) 
sql security definer 
  BEGIN 
    declare sql_stmt varchar(416) 
     default concat('RENAME USER ', _oldname,' TO ', _newname); 
    prepare stmt from sql_stmt; 
    IF (SELECT COUNT(User) 
     FROM mysql.user WHERE User = _oldname) > 0 
      THEN 
       BEGIN 
         execute stmt;
         deallocate prepare stmt; 
       END; 
    END IF; 
  END$$ 

delimiter ;
```

Then `call renamedbuser('test','testing');`